# Too many values on X

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have values for each hour and I'm trying to make it nicer because the x label is unreadable, I can't make it smaller because it's is sufficiently the case.

Is there any simple way to improve it? maybe display x1, x3, x5, x7. It suits me if I can display in this way, but how to do this?

Here is data:

```
    k1=structure(list(Heure = structure(c(428L, 7L, 11L, 20L, 28L, 41L, 
57L, 75L, 92L, 112L, 128L, 138L, 146L, 154L, 163L, 425L, 8L, 
12L, 16L, 21L, 29L, 42L, 129L, 140L, 147L, 155L, 164L, 52L, 61L, 
70L, 79L, 87L, 97L, 107L, 117L, 2L, 10L, 18L, 27L, 32L, 39L, 
46L, 54L, 63L, 72L, 81L, 89L, 99L, 109L, 119L, 136L, 145L, 153L, 
162L, 15L, 24L, 34L, 48L, 66L, 84L, 102L, 122L, 133L, 142L, 149L, 
158L, 166L, 25L, 35L, 49L, 58L, 67L, 76L, 85L, 93L, 103L, 113L, 
123L, 134L, 143L, 150L, 159L, 55L, 64L, 73L, 82L, 90L, 100L, 
110L, 120L, 30L, 37L, 44L, 51L, 60L, 69L, 78L, 86L, 95L, 105L, 
115L, 126L, 26L, 430L, 1L, 5L, 14L, 23L, 131L, 141L, 148L, 156L, 
165L, 240L, 247L, 254L, 264L, 275L, 285L, 295L, 305L, 315L, 173L, 
181L, 189L, 197L, 205L, 213L, 221L, 230L, 363L, 373L, 381L, 389L, 
396L, 403L, 416L, 237L, 244L, 252L, 261L, 271L, 171L, 179L, 187L, 
195L, 203L, 211L, 219L, 228L, 236L, 251L, 269L, 290L, 310L, 329L, 
345L, 359L, 371L, 379L, 387L, 394L, 401L, 407L, 414L, 421L, 172L, 
180L, 188L, 196L, 204L, 212L, 220L, 229L, 239L, 253L, 380L, 388L, 
398L, 412L, 170L, 178L, 186L, 194L, 202L, 210L, 218L, 226L, 235L, 
249L, 266L, 287L, 307L, 326L, 343L, 357L, 370L, 378L, 386L, 393L, 
400L, 410L, 424L, 174L, 182L, 190L, 198L, 206L, 214L, 222L, 231L, 
243L, 259L, 280L, 300L, 320L, 338L, 352L, 365L, 374L, 382L, 390L, 
167L, 175L, 183L, 191L, 199L, 207L, 215L, 223L, 232L, 245L, 262L, 
273L, 283L, 293L, 303L, 313L, 323L, 332L, 340L, 347L, 354L, 361L, 
367L, 372L, 375L, 383L, 391L, 405L, 418L, 268L, 279L, 289L, 242L, 
256L, 277L, 297L, 317L, 335L, 349L), .Label = c("04:41:00", "04:56:00", 
"05:05:00", "05:10:00", "05:11:00", "05:15:00", "05:16:00", "05:20:00", 
"05:21:00", "05:25:00", "05:31:00", "05:35:00", "05:40:00", "05:41:00", 
"05:45:00", "05:50:00", "05:51:00", "05:56:00", "06:00:00", "06:01:00", 
"06:05:00", "06:10:00", "06:11:00", "06:15:00", "06:21:00", "06:23:00", 
"06:25:00", "06:30:00", "06:35:00", "06:38:00", "06:40:00", "06:41:00", 
"06:45:00", "06:46:00", "06:50:00", "06:51:00", "06:53:00", "06:55:00", 
"06:56:00", "07:00:00", "07:01:00", "07:04:00", "07:05:00", "07:08:00", 
"07:10:00", "07:11:00", "07:15:00", "07:16:00", "07:18:00", "07:19:00", 
"07:21:00", "07:24:00", "07:25:00", "07:27:00", "07:29:00", "07:30:00", 
"07:31:00", "07:33:00", "07:35:00", "07:36:00", "07:39:00", "07:40:00", 
"07:42:00", "07:44:00", "07:45:00", "07:46:00", "07:48:00", "07:49:00", 
"07:51:00", "07:54:00", "07:55:00", "07:57:00", "07:59:00", "08:00:00", 
"08:01:00", "08:03:00", "08:05:00", "08:06:00", "08:09:00", "08:10:00", 
"08:12:00", "08:14:00", "08:15:00", "08:16:00", "08:19:00", "08:21:00", 
"08:24:00", "08:25:00", "08:27:00", "08:29:00", "08:30:00", "08:31:00", 
"08:33:00", "08:35:00", "08:36:00", "08:37:00", "08:39:00", "08:40:00", 
"08:42:00", "08:44:00", "08:45:00", "08:46:00", "08:48:00", "08:50:00", 
"08:51:00", "08:52:00", "08:54:00", "08:55:00", "08:57:00", "08:59:00", 
"09:00:00", "09:01:00", "09:03:00", "09:05:00", "09:06:00", "09:07:00", 
"09:09:00", "09:10:00", "09:12:00", "09:14:00", "09:15:00", "09:16:00", 
"09:18:00", "09:20:00", "09:22:00", "09:25:00", "09:27:00", "09:30:00", 
"09:35:00", "09:37:00", "09:40:00", "09:42:00", "09:45:00", "09:50:00", 
"09:55:00", "09:56:00", "09:57:00", "10:00:00", "10:01:00", "10:05:00", 
"10:10:00", "10:15:00", "10:20:00", "10:25:00", "10:26:00", "10:30:00", 
"10:35:00", "10:40:00", "10:45:00", "10:50:00", "10:51:00", "10:55:00", 
"10:56:00", "11:00:00", "11:05:00", "11:09:00", "11:10:00", "11:15:00", 
"11:20:00", "11:21:00", "11:25:00", "11:26:00", "11:30:00", "11:35:00", 
"11:40:00", "11:45:00", "11:50:00", "11:51:00", "11:55:00", "11:56:00", 
"12:00:00", "12:05:00", "12:10:00", "12:15:00", "12:20:00", "12:21:00", 
"12:25:00", "12:26:00", "12:30:00", "12:35:00", "12:40:00", "12:45:00", 
"12:50:00", "12:51:00", "12:55:00", "12:56:00", "13:00:00", "13:05:00", 
"13:10:00", "13:15:00", "13:20:00", "13:21:00", "13:25:00", "13:26:00", 
"13:30:00", "13:35:00", "13:40:00", "13:45:00", "13:50:00", "13:51:00", 
"13:55:00", "13:56:00", "14:00:00", "14:05:00", "14:10:00", "14:15:00", 
"14:20:00", "14:21:00", "14:25:00", "14:26:00", "14:30:00", "14:35:00", 
"14:40:00", "14:45:00", "14:50:00", "14:51:00", "14:55:00", "14:56:00", 
"15:00:00", "15:05:00", "15:10:00", "15:15:00", "15:20:00", "15:21:00", 
"15:25:00", "15:26:00", "15:30:00", "15:31:00", "15:35:00", "15:40:00", 
"15:45:00", "15:50:00", "15:51:00", "15:55:00", "15:56:00", "16:00:00", 
"16:03:00", "16:05:00", "16:06:00", "16:08:00", "16:10:00", "16:11:00", 
"16:15:00", "16:18:00", "16:20:00", "16:21:00", "16:23:00", "16:25:00", 
"16:26:00", "16:30:00", "16:31:00", "16:33:00", "16:35:00", "16:38:00", 
"16:40:00", "16:41:00", "16:43:00", "16:44:00", "16:46:00", "16:47:00", 
"16:48:00", "16:50:00", "16:52:00", "16:53:00", "16:54:00", "16:56:00", 
"16:58:00", "16:59:00", "17:01:00", "17:02:00", "17:03:00", "17:04:00", 
"17:05:00", "17:07:00", "17:08:00", "17:09:00", "17:11:00", "17:13:00", 
"17:14:00", "17:16:00", "17:17:00", "17:19:00", "17:20:00", "17:22:00", 
"17:23:00", "17:24:00", "17:26:00", "17:28:00", "17:29:00", "17:31:00", 
"17:32:00", "17:34:00", "17:35:00", "17:37:00", "17:38:00", "17:39:00", 
"17:41:00", "17:43:00", "17:44:00", "17:45:00", "17:47:00", "17:49:00", 
"17:50:00", "17:52:00", "17:53:00", "17:54:00", "17:56:00", "17:58:00", 
"17:59:00", "18:01:00", "18:02:00", "18:04:00", "18:05:00", "18:07:00", 
"18:08:00", "18:09:00", "18:11:00", "18:13:00", "18:14:00", "18:15:00", 
"18:17:00", "18:19:00", "18:20:00", "18:22:00", "18:24:00", "18:26:00", 
"18:28:00", "18:29:00", "18:30:00", "18:32:00", "18:34:00", "18:35:00", 
"18:37:00", "18:39:00", "18:41:00", "18:43:00", "18:44:00", "18:45:00", 
"18:49:00", "18:50:00", "18:52:00", "18:55:00", "18:56:00", "18:59:00", 
"19:00:00", "19:04:00", "19:05:00", "19:07:00", "19:10:00", "19:13:00", 
"19:14:00", "19:15:00", "19:18:00", "19:20:00", "19:22:00", "19:25:00", 
"19:26:00", "19:29:00", "19:30:00", "19:33:00", "19:35:00", "19:37:00", 
"19:40:00", "19:43:00", "19:45:00", "19:49:00", "19:50:00", "19:52:00", 
"19:55:00", "19:56:00", "20:00:00", "20:05:00", "20:10:00", "20:15:00", 
"20:20:00", "20:21:00", "20:25:00", "20:26:00", "20:30:00", "20:35:00", 
"20:40:00", "20:45:00", "20:50:00", "20:51:00", "20:55:00", "20:56:00", 
"21:00:00", "21:05:00", "21:10:00", "21:15:00", "21:20:00", "21:21:00", 
"21:26:00", "21:30:00", "21:35:00", "21:40:00", "21:45:00", "21:49:00", 
"21:51:00", "21:56:00", "22:00:00", "22:05:00", "22:10:00", "22:15:00", 
"22:19:00", "22:21:00", "22:30:00", "22:35:00", "22:40:00", "22:41:00", 
"22:45:00", "22:49:00", "22:51:00", "23:00:00", "23:05:00", "23:10:00", 
"23:15:00", "23:19:00", "23:21:00", "23:30:00", "23:31:00", "23:35:00", 
"23:40:00", "23:41:00", "23:49:00", "23:51:00", "24:00:00", "24:01:00", 
"24:05:00", "24:10:00", "24:21:00", "24:30:00", "24:40:00", "24:50:00"
), class = "factor"), X = c(9L, 1L, 14L, 7L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 67L, 
84L, 50L, 32L, 28L, 24L, 33L, 26L, 9L, 57L, 7L, 22L, 13L, 22L, 
17L, 30L, 39L, 26L, 33L, 21L, 35L, 16L, 38L, 42L, 45L, 18L, 9L, 
24L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 28L, 5L, 21L, 28L, 21L, 41L, 47L, 101L, 107L, 
62L, 69L, 10L, 34L, 8L, 15L, 17L, 6L, 15L, 17L, 21L, 36L, 59L, 
84L, 54L, 36L, 54L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 21L, 26L, 26L, 32L, 49L, 42L, 
46L, 130L, 101L, 50L, 48L, 54L, 70L, 20L, 56L, 8L, 12L, 28L, 
22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 31L, 2L, 17L, 24L, 11L, 8L, 31L, 24L, 31L, 
45L, 74L, 18L, 44L, 51L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 0L, 4L, 22L, 48L, 0L, 6L, 
13L, 35L, 55L, 24L, 42L, 52L, 65L, 62L, 40L, 43L, 23L, 23L, 13L, 
22L, 5L, 15L, 20L, 18L, 34L, 49L, 11L, 19L, 13L, 18L, 2L, 18L, 
25L, 30L, 25L, 63L, 34L, 17L, 44L, 25L, 38L, 22L, 16L, 46L, 34L, 
77L, 32L, 73L, 49L, 71L, 43L, 33L, 30L, 35L, 31L, 29L, 8L, 20L, 
9L, 29L, 36L, 58L, 24L, 32L, 21L, 31L, 47L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 26L, 
0L, 21L, 15L, 23L, 31L, 7L, 19L, 14L, 29L, 11L, 37L, 36L, 6L, 
13L, 57L, 37L, 90L, 57L, 45L, 41L, 19L, 8L, 17L, 13L, 28L, 6L, 
44L, 76L, 29L, 54L, 43L, 24L, 17L, 22L, 42L, 58L, 30L, 44L, 62L, 
86L, 72L, 65L, 28L, 17L, 31L, 45L, 32L, 39L, 25L, 48L, 35L, 33L, 
29L, 31L, 41L, 31L, 30L, 82L, 89L, 75L, 81L, 80L, 95L, 79L, 66L, 
67L, 64L, 44L, 52L, 38L, 26L, 27L, 6L, 4L, 53L, 69L, 45L, 23L, 
14L, 49L, 51L, 58L, 55L, 31L), Y = c(26L, 120L, 65L, 79L, 173L, 
239L, 282L, 313L, 438L, 330L, 238L, 149L, 119L, 79L, 57L, 18L, 
27L, 35L, 34L, 65L, 163L, 216L, 167L, 101L, 89L, 64L, 74L, 328L, 
309L, 366L, 278L, 426L, 450L, 442L, 341L, 8L, 53L, 85L, 150L, 
139L, 189L, 256L, 344L, 389L, 507L, 587L, 553L, 497L, 525L, 247L, 
376L, 149L, 205L, 263L, 134L, 92L, 175L, 311L, 308L, 395L, 445L, 
367L, 189L, 141L, 114L, 101L, 86L, 94L, 172L, 194L, 215L, 311L, 
330L, 452L, 420L, 296L, 249L, 220L, 171L, 121L, 196L, 72L, 239L, 
347L, 467L, 442L, 500L, 414L, 319L, 333L, 204L, 318L, 384L, 243L, 
197L, 311L, 353L, 378L, 365L, 538L, 298L, 334L, 0L, 19L, 14L, 
14L, 111L, 154L, 494L, 198L, 0L, 163L, 141L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 123L, 164L, 158L, 127L, 110L, 98L, 132L, 
108L, 77L, 68L, 61L, 32L, 38L, 27L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
96L, 115L, 65L, 97L, 69L, 113L, 42L, 150L, 114L, 189L, 208L, 
278L, 221L, 233L, 155L, 128L, 49L, 86L, 53L, 38L, 32L, 98L, 45L, 
25L, 56L, 56L, 62L, 66L, 68L, 70L, 62L, 48L, 76L, 76L, 34L, 0L, 
48L, 35L, 137L, 91L, 110L, 135L, 110L, 101L, 93L, 69L, 93L, 68L, 
107L, 139L, 194L, 156L, 120L, 123L, 96L, 49L, 43L, 65L, 32L, 
43L, 22L, 123L, 72L, 112L, 76L, 100L, 122L, 106L, 99L, 174L, 
169L, 253L, 338L, 286L, 267L, 222L, 151L, 70L, 65L, 49L, 114L, 
58L, 91L, 72L, 92L, 73L, 64L, 81L, 75L, 93L, 93L, 97L, 145L, 
130L, 157L, 119L, 114L, 90L, 118L, 85L, 62L, 100L, 54L, 77L, 
42L, 38L, 45L, 12L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 109L, 110L, 183L, 197L, 
121L, 134L, 92L), Z = c(40L, 37L, 120L, 247L, 236L, 318L, 421L, 
468L, 721L, 535L, 352L, 207L, 257L, 167L, 176L, 22L, 130L, 98L, 
133L, 128L, 177L, 222L, 355L, 228L, 178L, 115L, 187L, 458L, 369L, 
469L, 413L, 593L, 464L, 466L, 360L, 42L, 160L, 219L, 390L, 378L, 
450L, 501L, 527L, 646L, 755L, 1002L, 1045L, 803L, 645L, 709L, 
462L, 260L, 305L, 178L, 94L, 157L, 202L, 380L, 402L, 668L, 658L, 
413L, 215L, 229L, 129L, 162L, 146L, 193L, 235L, 269L, 332L, 386L, 
427L, 624L, 718L, 809L, 504L, 403L, 399L, 295L, 350L, 189L, 334L, 
405L, 644L, 563L, 692L, 504L, 483L, 416L, 311L, 429L, 382L, 338L, 
312L, 416L, 469L, 547L, 599L, 733L, 289L, 612L, 51L, 45L, 23L, 
60L, 113L, 236L, 606L, 425L, 0L, 177L, 172L, 35L, 55L, 24L, 42L, 
52L, 65L, 62L, 40L, 43L, 215L, 248L, 158L, 268L, 127L, 193L, 
194L, 193L, 143L, 85L, 92L, 72L, 51L, 47L, 59L, 18L, 25L, 30L, 
25L, 63L, 142L, 177L, 181L, 185L, 166L, 130L, 140L, 521L, 224L, 
253L, 310L, 363L, 262L, 317L, 187L, 143L, 113L, 117L, 93L, 61L, 
74L, 76L, 55L, 62L, 189L, 152L, 95L, 160L, 112L, 152L, 157L, 
129L, 112L, 136L, 79L, 0L, 71L, 60L, 195L, 224L, 212L, 274L, 
215L, 273L, 128L, 243L, 195L, 210L, 223L, 299L, 324L, 215L, 239L, 
197L, 200L, 83L, 65L, 50L, 49L, 77L, 57L, 153L, 221L, 186L, 180L, 
208L, 198L, 175L, 244L, 365L, 399L, 423L, 455L, 448L, 410L, 265L, 
210L, 149L, 135L, 100L, 208L, 217L, 255L, 203L, 212L, 127L, 169L, 
128L, 203L, 174L, 181L, 210L, 304L, 301L, 268L, 320L, 277L, 304L, 
188L, 127L, 131L, 156L, 135L, 162L, 107L, 70L, 133L, 54L, 24L, 
53L, 69L, 45L, 185L, 192L, 379L, 294L, 296L, 338L, 204L)), .Names = c("Heure", 
"X", "Y", "Z"), row.names = c(NA, -261L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code:

```
meltk1 = melt(k1, id = "Heure")
ggplot(meltk1, aes(x=Heure , y = value, group = variable, colour = variable)) +
   geom_line(size=1) + scale_x_discrete(name="Heure") + theme_bw() +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16,lineheight=2, face="bold"),
   legend.text=element_text(size=14),
   legend.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
   axis.text.y = element_text(size=12),
   axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle=45),
   strip.background = element_rect(fill = "White") ) 
   ggsave(filename=paste("Dynamique",".tiff", sep = ""), width = 80, height = 30, units = "cm")
```

[image]

EDIT : 
I convert `Heure`with this code :

```
Heure=strptime(mydata1$Heure,format='%H:%M:%S')
```

It gives me only 7 values of X and it is not enough. I need at least one value per two.

[image]

EDIT2 : look on red square about 2:00 and 3:00
[image]

EDIT 3 : This is what I obtain when i run your code. The same problem,I re-run R several times.It's strange I don't have the same plot that yours
[image]

EDIT4 : Problem of TZ, the follow code solve the issue, only "last" problem I hope, it do not interpret the 24:00:00. I can't convert it on 00:00:00 because it signify that it is the same day while 24:00:00 means the follwing days. It seems complex as issue.

```
k1$Hour=strptime(as.character(k1$Heure),format='%H:%M:%S',tz="Etc/GMT")
meltk1$Hour=strptime(as.character(meltk1$Heure),format='%H:%M:%S',tz="Etc/GMT")
```

Comment: your time is a `factor`. If you have it as a date/time object, the plot will work

Comment: Another thing to consider is that currently the plot shows each space as equal, when the time intervals are not equal.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Richard, I didn't notice factors issue in this case.

Comment: `Heure=strptime(as.character(meltk1$Heure),format='%H:%M:%S')`

You need to make it a character variable first, otherwise R thinks it's looking at just numbers.

Comment: For those observations I would just change them manually to move the day forward or fill in the value manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below with explanation and image. It's important to change the `Heure` variable to an actual time variable since the time intervals are not uniform.

```
#load the required packages
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


#Omitted data load step
meltk1 = melt(k1, id = "Heure")
#Now add a variable that will be the hour, but format it to POSXICT
k1$Hour=strptime(as.character(k1$Heure),format='%H:%M:%S')
meltk1$Hour=strptime(as.character(meltk1$Heure),format='%H:%M:%S')

#Note that a few values were set to missing. I don't know why but think you should investigate.

ggplot(meltk1, aes(x=Hour , y = value, group = variable, colour = variable)) +
        geom_line(size=1) + 
        scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S")) +  
        theme_bw() +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16,lineheight=2, face="bold"),
              legend.text=element_text(size=14),
              legend.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size=12),
              axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle=45),
              strip.background = element_rect(fill = "White") )
```

The line with scale_x_datetime is the most important part. Here I set the breaks to be 1 hour apart, you can change it to various levels, see the Help file. The format needs to be applied this way, otherwise it will also add the date.
End result is a wonderful looking chart:

[image]

However, it looks like a few your times are in a format that can't be parsed with `strptime`, so you'll have to manually edit these.

Comment: This is perfect for me, thanks a lot for your precious help !

Comment: Sure thing. I still think you should change `Heure` to be a time variable so the intervals are shown accurately. Right now it could be a lot or little time between data points, and you can't tell.

Comment: I saw your EDIT right now, it seems perfect, but when I verify the plot, I notice that it display value for 02:00 and 03:00 while I have no values at this interval of time. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm looking at the plot and don't see values at 02.00 and 03.00. Do you mean that the x-axis goes too far (to 04:00 on the left and 00:00 on the right)?

maybe post a picture and highlight the problem areas.

Comment: Please take a look on EDIT 2 in the red square. I should have no values for these hours.

Comment: Reload the data and try running the edited answer -- there must have been a glitch in my workspace.

Comment: Please take a look on EDIT 3, Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but this seems to have something to do with the `strptime` function. It seems like we are on different time zones (are you in Germany?) so perhaps R is adjusting for that, I am not sure. I think there is a `tz` option in `strptime` that will let you put in the proper timezone for the data.

Comment: Oh, didn't think about that ! I'm in France, in fact it is the same time zone than Germany, will look on strptime options' and come back with the result, thanks a lot because I'm sure that i won't be able to find that by myself :)

Comment: the tz="Etc/GMT" solve the problem (look on EDIT4), thanks again for all :)

Comment: Not sure if I have the dates right, but do this to fix the two values with problematic:

`as.character(k1$Heure)[is.na(k1$Hour)] 
k1$Hour[is.na(k1$Hour)] <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2016-05-10 00:01:00","2016-05-10 00:10:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))`

Comment: Yours suggestions solved all my issues. It is perfect. I really appreciate your help ! Thanks ! :)