# Convert character (or object) variable to numeric (or datetime) variable

Tags: python, r, datetime, ggplot2

I have a monthly data on sales volumes:

```
YearMonth     Sales Count
2010-04       300
2010-05       342
2010-06       425
```

and I just want to draw a line graph in r to observe the trend.

I use ggplot2 in r:

```
ggplot(data,
   aes(x = YearMonth, y = `Sales Count`)) +
   geom_line()
```

However, r gives me an error message:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. 
Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

I tried many ways to convert variable "YearMonth" to a numeric variable, but they all don't work...

Because the data was generated in python, I checked the data type using:

```
data.dtypes
```

and it returns

```
YearMonth           object
Sales Count         int64
dtype: object
```

I tried to convert it using

```
data['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(data['YearMonth'])
```

but it converts everything to the first day of the month, i.e. the data now looks like:

```
YearMonth        Sales Count
2010-04-01       300
2010-05-01       342
2010-06-01       425
```

Because the x-axis should be each month rather than the first day of each month, is there anyway to keep just the month and plot it as a numeric or datetime variable?

Many thanks!!

**EDITS**

Actually when I plot it in r, it only shows years like 2010, 2011 on the x-axis... So the issue above does not matter, if we can change what is shown on the x-axis. Is there a way to define what can be shown on the x-axis, like showing 2010 April, 2010 May, rather than just the year?

**SOLUTION**

Combining answers from @Jon Spring and @ThomasPepperz, the following codes give me exactly what I want:

```
data[['YearMonth']] = lubridate::ymd(paste(data[['YearMonth']], 1))

ggplot(stats8, aes(YearMonth, `Sales Count`)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months",
               date_labels = "%Y %b") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Comment: add `group = 1`, `ggplot(df,aes(x = YearMonth, y = SalesCount, group  =1)) +  geom_line()` If you google your error message it should lead you the marked post.

Comment: For me it displays what you have in `YearMonth` column on X-axis which is `2010-04`, `2010-05`. What do you need ?

Comment: @RonakShah, thanks a lot for the fast reply! group=1 really works for only a few points. My problem with it is I have too many observations, and the x-axis have all the values overlap with each other... I know we can add a date or time break if the x-value is stored as datetime. But since here it is stored as character, can we still only display every a few months, rather than display all the months on x-axis?

Comment: we can aggregate the data and then plot. Can you post few more rows with some overlap dates and explain what you would like in the output. I'll reopen the post.

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion, what I mean by overlap is that there are too many labels on the axis so I can't see which month corresponds to which data, like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080756/too-many-values-on-x  But the method in that post doesn't work for me, because my data is character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data$date = lubridate::ymd(paste(data$YearMonth, 1))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(date, Sales_Count)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month",
               date_labels = "%Y %b")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This works perfectly for me - the x-axis is now very clear after I change the date_breaks to 6 months. May I ask, (1) what does "paste" in the ymd function do, and (2) what does "%b" mean in date_lables? Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: `paste` is a base R function that concatenates strings; lubridate's `ymd` function expects a year then month then day. R has a variety of codes for date formatting, for instance %y is YY and %Y is YYYY. %b happens to be abbreviated month: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and references, @Jon Spring! This really solves my problem, and teaches me how it is solved. Sorry for another question - I am trying to learn r and am reading the document on `paste`: paste (..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL). It says the second argument is how we want to separate the data. Does `1` in your code mean we don't need to separate the data?

Comment: No, the 1 is getting pasted on afterwards, with default `sep`aration of a space, so that "2010-04" is transformed into "2010-04 1". Lubridate is pretty robust and will treat spaces, dashes, slashes, etc. as separators between terms, so it should consistently turn that into the right date.

Comment: Ohh this makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much for all the detailed explanations, Jon Spring!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df$YearMonth = lubridate::as_date(as.character(df$YearMonth), '%Y-%m')
df$month = lubridate::month(df$YearMonth)
```

Use 'lubridate' to convert to a date object and then use month() to extract only the month and store it as a new variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! It makes a lot of sense, but there are two problems with it: (1) lubricate works weirdly here... It converts 2004-06 to 2020-04-06 and I get an error message: Warning message:
 72 failed to parse. (2) The second line only gives me the month, for example, it gives 6 rather than 2014-06, which is what I need to put on the x-axis. The reason is, there are also data from 2015-06, 2017-06, etc. If I only extract the month, I can't distinguish between the years...

Comment: If you're data is of the format "2010-04" it shouldn't fail to parse. Ensure that you're data is as originally posted and not as 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: Try turning the x-axis labels sideways to make more room if you need to.
```ggplot(...)+...+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))```
Also, ```lubridate::months(df, format = " ", labels = TRUE)``` will produce abbreviated month labels.

Comment: This helps a lot and I have been looking for a way to turn the x-axis labels to an angle. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Regarding the abbreviation, I got an error message... Error: 'months' is not an exported object from 'namespace:lubridate'